# Jaynes Cummings Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-optics, two-level-system

Hamiltonian of Jaynes-Cummings model has in Schrodinger picture form:
$$
H=\frac{1}{2}\hbar\omega\sigma_{z}+\hbar\omega a^{\dagger}a+\lambda\hbar(\sigma_{+}\hat{a}+\sigma_{-}\hat{a}^{\dagger})
$$
which we can split into two parts
$$
H_{0}=\frac{1}{2}\hbar\omega\sigma_{z}+\hbar\omega a^{\dagger}a
$$
and 
$$
V=\lambda\hbar(\sigma_{+}\hat{a}+\sigma_{-}\hat{a}^{\dagger})
$$
Any sugesstion, how to prove commutation relation?
$$
[H_{0},V]=0
$$

Comment: You mean aside from plugging and chugging?

Comment: I meant, how to derive that comtator. When you plug in H and V in it

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that the commutator is linear $$[A,B+C]=[A,B]+[A,C]$$ and that pauli matrices $\sigma_i$ commute with $a^+$ and $a$, we only need the following commutation relations 
$$[\sigma_i,\sigma_j]=2i\epsilon_{ijk}\sigma_k$$
$$[N,a^+]=a^{+}$$
$$[N,a]=-a$$
where $N=a^{+}a$